# Html rendering using ternary operator in Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Razor instruction shown below:

```
<td@(IsAdmin ? " class=editable name" : "") data-attr="name">it's true</td>
```

results in:

```
<td class="editable" data-attr="name" name="">it's true</td>
```

while I need this:

```
<td class="editable name" data-attr="name">it's true</td>
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
<td @Html.Raw(IsAdmin ? " class=\"editable name\"" : "") data-attr="name">it's true</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `@(IsAdmin ? " class=\"editable name\"" : "")`

Comment: I've checked this before and it results in: <td class=""editable" data-attr="name" name&quot;="">it's true</td>

Comment: Using view source it gives: <td class=&quot;editable name&quot; data-attr="name">it's true</td>